# "bash: export: `-Xmx512m': not a valid identifier" this error occured,How to fix that error

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

When I opened ubuntu terminal I see the error:

> bash: export: `-Xmx512m': not a valid identifier

How can I fix this?

I tried `export foo-Xmx512mbar` but it did not help.

Comment: Bash identifiers can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores, so "-Xmx512m" is not a valid identifier. This isn't a bug. What are you actually trying to do?